# innerText não aceita espaço em branco

Tags: php, javascript

Por algum motivo, quando uso espaço em branco, passando algo para o `innerText` não acontece nada. Se eu passar 'Bom_dia' aparece tudo normalmente, mas se eu passar 'Bom dia' ele não mostra nada.

```
onmousemove = window.parent.document.getElementById('calendario_obs').innerText=
'$rodape'>$cont</text>
```

Se a variável `$rodape` tiver como conteúdo 'Bom_dia' aparece normal, mas se tiver 'Bom dia' nada acontece. Se eu tiro a variável e coloco direto o valor acontece o mesmo erro então não deve ter nada a ver com a variável em PHP. Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Tem como revisar o valor que está sendo atribuído ao `innerText`? Está parecendo uma *tag* estranha `</text>` que não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Oi, ele está dentro de uma tag text mesmo, precisa estar, a instrução completa fica assim: $texto_dia="<text class=\"font_botao_carmesim\" onclick=window.parent.document.getElementById('frame_calendario_variavel').src='calendario_variaveis.php?dia=$cont'; onmousemove=window.parent.document.getElementById('calendario_obs').innerText='$rodape'>$cont</text>"; somente o final da problema, se a variável rodapé tiver espaço não aparece, se não tiver funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Pelo que parece você só está esquecendo as aspas no onmousemove, no html as aspas só não são obrigatórias caso não exista nenhuma espaço, logo seu código iria até "bom"  criando uma string incompleta ` 'bom` e ignoraria o resto,dando variável `bom` indefinida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre use aspas para valores de atributos
O HTML não te obriga a utilizar aspas, mas recomendo que sempre use para evitar esse tipo de problema.

#### Causa do problema:

Ao não usar aspas, o resultado do seu código fica:
Assumindo "bom dia" como valor da variável `$rodapé`

```
onmousemove=window.parent.document.getElementById('calendario_obs').innerText='bom dia>$cont</text>
```

Os navegadores colocarão as aspas ficando:

```
onmousemove="window.parent.document.getElementById('calendario_obs').innerText='bom">$cont</text>
```

cortando o `dia'` e ignorando-o;

ou

```
onmousemove="window.parent.document.getElementById('calendario_obs').innerText='bom" dia>$cont</text>
```

cortando o `dia`, removendo a aspas simples do final e colocando-o como um novo atributo na tag sem valor.

Como o JS desconsidera essa aspas simples "órfã" (como está em `'bom`), ele tenta procurar `bom` como sendo uma variável, logo dará que a variável é indefinida (pode conferir no console, possivelmente estará lá).

#### Como corrigir:

Apenas adicione as aspas em volta de todo o código JS.
O seu código deve ser então:

```
onmousemove = "window.parent.document.getElementById('calendario_obs').innerText='$rodape'">$cont</text>
```

#### Quando posso não usar aspas?

Quando seu atributo não contenha NENHUM espaço, pois a separação de atributos na tag é feita por ele.

Comment: Perfeitamente, muuuuuito obrigado.